# How do Linux binary installers (.bin, .sh) work?

Tags: linux, installation

Some software (for ex. the [NetBeans IDE](http://www.netbeans.org)) ship the Linux installers in .sh files. Curious about how exactly they 'package' a whole IDE into a 'shell script', I opened the file in an editor. I saw some plain text shell scripting code and then some random gibberish, which I reckon is 'binary' or non-plain text.

I am wondering how they mix plain shell scripts and then probably call the 'non-readable' stuff, which would be the binaries.

Any insight on this?

Comment: I chose Curt's answer because he explained the process, rather than pointing to a tool which does it. 

Thank You Seb, James, and Nik.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Basically, it's a shell script prepended to a compressed archive of some sort, such as a tar archive. You use the `tail` or `sed` command on yourself (the `$0` variable in Bourne shell) to strip off the shell script at the front and pass the rest to your unarchiver.

For example, create the following script as `self-extracting`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
sed -e '1,/^exit$/d' "$0" | tar xzf - && ./project/Setup
exit
```

The `sed` command above deletes all lines from the first line of the file to the first one that starts with "exit", and then passes the rest on through. If what starts immediately after the "exit" line is a tar file, the `tar` command will extract it. If that's successful, the `./project/Setup` file (presumably extracted from the tarball) will be executed.

Then:

```
mkdir project
echo "#!/bin/sh" > project/Setup
echo "echo This is the setup script!" >> project/Setup
chmod +x project/Setup
tar czf - project >> self-extracting
```

Now, if you get rid of your old `project` directory, you can run `self-extracting` and it will extract that tar file and run the setup script.

Comment: How do the shell script interact with the archive contents?( which is probably is some other language- assembly/binary/bytecodes)

Comment: In many actual cases, the binary portion will be base64 encoded or some other such encoding so that the entire file contains only printable characters.

Comment: Amit: once you've extracted the archive, it's just files on the disk, and you can do whatever any shell script can do with files on the disk. My example runs a setup script that was extracted from the archive.

Comment: Yes, Curt. Thank You very much, It was a very nice and simple explanation.

Comment: `sed` won't work correctly on Darwin, as it appends a \n at the end of the extracted file. Use grep/cut/tail (see @seb's answer) on Macs.

Answer (score 54):

You might want to check out [`makeself.sh`](http://megastep.org/makeself/)

From the authors' notes.

> **makeself.sh** is a small shell script that generates a self-extractable tar.gz archive from a directory. The resulting file appears as a shell script (many of those have a .run suffix), and can be launched as is. The archive will then uncompress itself to a temporary directory and an optional arbitrary command will be executed (for example an installation script).
>
> Makeself archives also include checksums for integrity self-validation (CRC and/or MD5 checksums).
>
> The makeself.sh script itself is used only to create the archives from a directory of files. The resultant archive is actually a compressed (using gzip, bzip2, or compress) TAR archive, with a small shell script stub at the beginning. This small stub performs all the steps of extracting the files, running the embedded command, and removing the temporary files when it's all over. All what the user has to do to install the software contained in such an archive is to "run" the archive [that is execute the script]
>
> I am trying to keep the code of this script as portable as possible, i.e it's not relying on any bash-specific features and only calls commands that are installed on any functioning UNIX-compatible system. This script as well as the archives it generates should run on any Unix flavor, with any compatible Bourne shell, provided of course that the compression programs are available.

Finally, the `makeself` package itself comes as a self-extracting script called [`makeself.run`](http://megastep.org/makeself/makeself.run).

Comment: Cool, there is even a package in the Ubuntu repository! sudo apt-get install makeself

Comment: [how-to-create-a-self-extracting-archive-or-installer-in-linux](https://www.xmodulo.com/how-to-create-a-self-extracting-archive-or-installer-in-linux.html)

Answer (score 13):

[Add a Binary Payload to your Shell Scripts](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/add-binary-payload-your-shell-scripts)

Answer (score 5):

GNU sharutils:

http://www.gnu.org/software/sharutils/

is a toolset for creating shell archives, and provides some additional features that may be helpful (such as checksums to ensuring that the payload is not damaged in transit).

Protecting against malicious modifications is not really feasible when the final product has to be interpretable by the shell - anyone who understood the generation technique could modify the checksum as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are also other/commercial software installer builder (like InstallAnywhere) they basically have their own version of shar/makeself.

Netbeans has their own installer engine, and part of it, which does the unpacking and launching is done in the NBI native launcher component: http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBINativeLaunchers

Creates a shell(script) archive for Linux/Unix/MacOS and native executable for Windows. You can use that tool for your own projects, also.