# Can I mix text with binary in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, fedora

I want to simplify installation of the app on Linux system, to make it sort of one click. To do that I hope to combine bash script with compressed tar.

So I have `install.sh` and `some_app.tar.gz` files.

Then I have an Ant task that does this:

```
cat install.sh some_app.tar.gz > some_app.exe
```

In short, file reads itself, decompresses tarball and extracts files and changes permissions.

When I run `install.sh` separately it works fine, but once I run `some_app.exe` it fails with the following error:

```
/some_app.exe: line 4: Binary file (standard input) matches + 1: arithmetic syntax error
```

So I wonder if text can be combined with binary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955460/how-do-linux-binary-installers-bin-sh-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perfectly feasible.

Example: http://www.stuartwells.net/slides/selfextract.htm

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are [Bash Self-Extracting Tar files](http://www.google.com/search?q=self+extracting+bash+script).

Answer (score 0):

Already done :P ... http://megastep.org/makeself/