# How to use find to bundle files

Tags: bash, find, bundle

I'm struggling with this task:

> Write a script that takes as input a directory (path) name  and a
>   filename base (such as ".", "*.txt", etc). The script shall search the
>   given directory tree, find all files matching the given filename, and
>   bundle them into a single file. Executing the given file as a script
>   should return the original files.

Can anyone help me?

First i tried to do the find part like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

filebase=$2
path=$1

find $path \( -name $base \)
```

Then i found this code for bundle, but I dont know how to combine them.

```
for i in $@; do
 echo "echo unpacking file $i"
 echo "cat > $i <<EOF"
 cat $i
 echo "EOF"
 done
```

Comment: did you take a look to this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/955490/718618

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your post to show what you have tried.  What research have your done?  What script have you written and what error messages is it giving?

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar

Answer (score 1):

Going on tripleee's comment you can use `shar` to generate a self extracting archive.
You can take the output of `find` and pass it through to `shar` in order to generate the archive.

```
#!/bin/bash

path="$1"
filebase="$2"
archive="$3"

find "$path" -type f -name "$filebase" | xargs shar > "$archive"
```

The `-type f` option passed to `find` will restrict the search to files (i.e. excludes directories), which seems to be a required limitation.

If the above script is called `archive_script.sh`, and is executable, then you can call it as below for example:

```
./archive_script.sh /etc '*.txt' etc-text.shar
```

This will create a `shar` archive of all the .txt files in /etc.