# How to include files in Linux Shell Script File?

Tags: linux, shell

What I want to do is including files in shell script program and 
copying files in local drive when it runs.
(like including resource file in other language ex) *.rc *.res)

I read some books and documents in websites. 
But any useful solution isn't there.

Is there any way I can use?

Comment: This question is very vague. Can you provide a concrete example of the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguous question. My linux program should contain some files and extract them in current directory when it runs. Before making program, I have to decide what language to use. My friend suggests shell programming. But because I'm newbie in that, I want to know it should been done in this language. Maybe it's too easy question to someone. But I spent all today to solve that question and can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Self-extractable shell script. These articles tell you how it work.
http://notepad2.blogspot.tw/2012/05/create-self-extractable-archive.html
[How do Linux binary installers (.bin, .sh) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955460/how-do-linux-binary-installers-bin-sh-work)
You can use [makeself.sh](http://megastep.org/makeself/) to generate shell script easily