# Embedding binary data in a script efficiently

Tags: python, bash, binaryfiles

I have seen some installation files (huge ones, install.sh for Matlab or Mathematica, for example) for Unix-like systems, they must have embedded quite a lot of binary data, such as icons, sound, graphics, etc, into the script. I am wondering how that can be done, since this can be potentially useful in simplifying file structure.

I am particularly interested in doing this with Python and/or Bash.

Existing methods that I know of in Python:

1. Just use a byte string: `x = b'\x23\xa3\xef' ...`, terribly inefficient, takes half a MB for a 100KB wav file.
2. base64, better than option 1, enlarge the size by a factor of 4/3.

I am wondering if there are other (better) ways to do this?

Comment: I very much doubt they are embedding the entire payload into the script.

Comment: I think they probably did, by looking at the size, it's several GB.

Comment: Your intro makes this question "too broad". If you're interested in efficient method for integrating binary data into script files, ask that..

Comment: Yes, I just edited the question.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955460/how-do-linux-binary-installers-bin-sh-work

Comment: Some languages, such as Bash, are forgiving enough to allow arbitrary binary data to be appended the end of a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use base64 + compression (using [bz2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html) for instance) if that suits your data (e.g., if you're not embedding already compressed data).

For instance, to create your data (say your data consist of 100 null bytes followed by 200 bytes with value 0x01):

```
>>> import bz2
>>> bz2.compress(b'\x00' * 100 + b'\x01' * 200).encode('base64').replace('\n', '')
'QlpoOTFBWSZTWcl9Q1UAAABBBGAAQAAEACAAIZpoM00SrccXckU4UJDJfUNV'
```

And to use it (in your script) to write the data to a file:

```
import bz2
data = 'QlpoOTFBWSZTWcl9Q1UAAABBBGAAQAAEACAAIZpoM00SrccXckU4UJDJfUNV'
with open('/tmp/testfile', 'w') as fdesc:
    fdesc.write(bz2.decompress(data.decode('base64')))
```

Comment: Nice, could you give a small example?

Comment: This answer doesn't work in Python 3, where the `bytes.encode` and `str.decode` methods do not exist (their types would be backwards from how text encoding works). You could `import base64` and use `base64.b64decode(data)` instead of `data.decode('base64')`, and similarly use `base64.b64encode` when creating the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty way. Create the following script called `MyInstaller`:

```
#!/bin/bash

dd if="$0" of=payload bs=1 skip=54

exit
```

Then append your binary to the script, and make it executable:

```
cat myBinary >> myInstaller
chmod +x myInstaller
```

When you run the script, it will copy the binary portion to a new file specified in the path `of=`. This could be a tar file or whatever, so you can do additional processing (unarchiving, setting execute permissions, etc) after the dd command. Just adjust the number in "skip" to reflect the total length of the script before the binary data starts.

Comment: A frequent use is a shell script to unzip the tarbal in the right place and some additional checks. Java packages for Linux were built like that.