# Create binaries that run on "all" Linux distrubtion

Tags: c++, linux, binary, compatibility, lsb

I know this question was probably asked a million times, but none of the questions have the answer with a how-to practical application and no one can explain what I'm going to show.

So, here's the problem: There are many software vendors that provide a single package that works on all Linux distributions, and when I say all, I mean at least the major ones (Debian, Redhat and Arch). I tried them, and they all work.

**My question is:** How are they doing this?

**What I know:** I know the old news about binary incompatibility. Please don't repeat that lecture. Anyone who wants to benefit from this question and the answers on it, please read more about binary incompatibility of Linux distributions if you never heard about it. The reason why I'm asking this question is because we have a practical application that ignores that incompatibility and works on almost all distributions. How is that happening?

I also know about the "rumor" called [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base). The reason I call it rumor, is that I never seen a single application of that thing anywhere, and if it's the way those vendors do it, please explain how in an answer.

Examples of software that works (almost) everywhere:

- [Qt Creator](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2), which works on many operating systems. It's just a single `.run` file that works everywhere.
- Mathematica, which provides a single `.sh` package that works everywhere. Following is a screenshot from their download page.
  [image]

(feel free to add more).

So how is this happening? How can I pull this off for my own applications?

**A satisfactory answer** will provide a mechanism (and best with a mini-example) where one can select a few Linux distributions (say Debian, CentOS and OpenSUSE), and have the recipe to create a single package that works/installs on all of them.

Thank you so much for any efforts.

Comment: A "binary" package necessarily targets only a single hardware platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The packages that you're referring to ... a ".run" or a ".sh" are just scripts.  Since people tend to want to 'just get the installation started' and could click on the wrong package, a shell script can detect what package would be appropriate, download and install it.

Or potentially even download and build the source ... somewhat depends on the project and aim of the package.

Comment: Packages are offline actually. Like Mathematica, is 1.2 GB and has everything.

Comment: In which case the packages will be bundled in the script in hex.

Comment: I would love to see examples on how that practically works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955460/how-do-linux-binary-installers-bin-sh-work

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the answer. Let me look into it and give you feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered packaging your app using appimage or flatpak?

http://appimage.org/

http://flatpak.org/

These are some of the ways you can create apps that works out of the box. I have used some of the apps packaged this way and they work out of the box across ubunut, fedora and other linux distros.

Comment: Cool! I'll look into them. Thanks!